# Tcl brace quoting: is everything literal inside braces?

Tags: tcl, interpreter, curly-braces

I have read that, everything is literal inside braace `{}` (except backslash-newline in Tcl.
So, this is expected:

```
% puts {\{}
\{
```

However, I do not understand properly the following:

```
% puts { {}
 <waits for close brace>
```

I would expect it to print `{`, since it is inside braces and should be taken literally. What I expect is: once you encounter a open brace, take everything literally until you encounter the first closing brace. But this does not seem to happen. Please clear my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Braces nest (unless quoted) inside a braced word because that's the rule ([6] in the Dodekalogue). The reason for this rule is that the contents of a braced word is very often a structured expression with several open and close braces, quite possibly even several *levels* of open and close braces. The benefit of having the parser complain about unbalanced braces outweighs the hassle of having to quote the braces when you *aren't* using them to structure the expression.

[Tcl syntax](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Braces are always a nightmare at the begging for a `Tcl` programmer.

As you know already, major thumb rule with braces is as follows,

**Rule 1 : No substitutions occur inside braces**

Other than the above rule, we have few more in `Tcl`.

One of the most important uses for braces is to `defer evaluation`.

**Rule 2  : Deferred evaluation**

It means that special characters aren’t processed immediately by the `Tcl` parser.

Instead they will be passed to the command procedure as part of its argument and the command procedure will process the special characters itself. Braces are almost always used when passing scripts to `Tcl` commands, as in the following example that computes the factorial of five:

```
   set result 1 
   set i 5 
   while {$i > 0} { 
         set result [expr $result*$i] 
         set i [expr $i-1] 
   }
```

The body of the `while` loop is enclosed in braces to defer substitutions. `While` passes the script back into `Tcl` for evaluation during each iteration of the loop and the subsitutions will be performed at that time. In this case it is important to defer the substitutions so that they are done afresh each time that while evaluates the loop body, rather than once-and-for-all while parsing the while command.

**Rule 3 : Braces nest.** The last word of the `proc` command starts after the open brace on the first line and contains everything up to the close brace on the last line.

**Rule 4 : The Tcl interpreter removes the outer braces and passes everything between them, including several nested pairs of braces, to `proc` as an argument.**

```
proc power {base p} { 
    set result 1 
    while {$p > 0} { 
          set result [expr $result*base] 
          set p [expr $p-1] 
     } 
    return $result 
}
```

In the above case the third argument to `proc` contains two pairs of nested braces (the outermost braces are removed by the `Tcl` parser). The command substitution requested with `[expr $p-1]` will not be performed when the `proc` command is parsed, or even when the `while` command is parsed as part of executing the procedure’s body, but only when `while` evaluates its second argument to execute the loop.

**Rule 5 : If a brace is backslashed then it does not count in ending the matching close brace for a word enclosed in braces. The backslash will not be removed when the word is parsed.**

As explained in the rule 4, in the code `puts {\{}`, after removing outer braces, we have `\{`  alone. That will be passed to `puts` command. Now, as per rule 5, in `\{`, when `Tcl` encounters the backslased open brace, it will not try to match a close brace. Also, that backslash will not be removed when parsed. This is why `\{` is getting printed in console.

In case of `puts {{}`, the Tcl interpreter will obviously wait for the close braces since it is unbalanced.

**Note:** There will be an exception in all places. Well, `Tcl` has the same when it comes to braces. We started saying No substitution inside braces. But, **the only form of substitution that occurs between braces is for backslash-newline.**

In `Tcl`, `backslash` is also used for line continuation.

```
if 1 {
 puts "Brace Yourself!!!"
}
```

You can re-write the above as

```
if 1 \
{
 puts "Brace Yourself!!!"
}
```

The same way, with backslash-newline, substitution will occur as shown below.

```
puts {Thanks to\
Stackoverflow}
```

The output of the code will be seen in a single line.

Reference : [Tcl and the Tk Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133633X)

Comment: You can use other forms of quoting with Tcl commands. Try it once; it works! `proc addThings "a b" "return \[expr {\$a + \$b}\]"`. Don't try it again though; it's incredibly annoying to keep doing…